# Can't mass-assign protected attributes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't understand what's wrong with my code (Rails 4):

parameters from post:

```
{:name => "name"}
```

new action:

```
m=Menu.new(params.permit(:name))
```

Last line of this code generates "Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Menu: name"

Comment: Are you migrating from Rails 3 and using the protected_attributes gem [https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes)?

Comment: Yes. Can I use protected_attributes with strong parameters?

Comment: Yes, but it is recommended to migrate the attribute protection logic from protected_attributes to strong parameters. If you want to keep both, you will have to add `attr_accessible :name` in your `Menu` model, but I would remove protected_attributes and apply strong_parameters in every action as it is the preferred way in Rails 4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard way to use strong_parameters in Rails 4 is to create a private method in the controller that defines the permitted params.  Like so:

```
def new
  @m = Menu.new(menu_params)
end

private

def menu_params
  params.require(:menu).permit(:name, :etc, :etc)
end
```

Then, you can remove the attr_accessible line from the model.

See:

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html
http://railscasts.com/episodes/371-strong-parameters