# Rails: How can I change Boolean values in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called "Clients". The Clients model belongs to the Users model (Users model is associated with devise). The Client can do payments to me manually (cash only). When the client does this payment, I give them access to more pages in the website. To do this, I was thinking I add a migration to the Client model like:

```
rails generate migration add_paid_to_clients paid:boolean
```

Then when the clients pay the money, I can just go to their profile and click on an option (maybe a checkbox) saying the client has paid. Only the admin(me) can see this part. The way I would implement that is, in the user profile view:

```
<% if current_user.user_type == :client%>
    userinformation....blablabla
<% elsif current_user.user_type == :admin %>
    userinformation....blablabla
    AND the checkbox I talked about.
<% end %>
```

The user_type is a predefined function to figure out if the current_user is admin or just a client. I have done this part.

So in the private pages(the pages you can get access to after paying), I can have some logic like `If current_user.paid? THEN show them this page.`

How can I implement the checkbox part? After the migration(if there is a better way,please let me know),how can I just "flip the switch" to let them get more access?

My Clients contoller:

```
class ClientController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_client, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index 
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @client = current_user.build_client
    end

    def create
        @client = current_user.build_client(client_params)
        if @client.save
          redirect_to clients_path
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
    end

    def destroy
        @client.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private
        def client_params
            params.require(:client).permit(:name, :company, :position, :number, :email, :client_img)
        end

        def find_client
            @client = Client.find(params[:id])
        end 
end
```

This is not real cash, this is a project for school.

Comment: Don't forget to protect your new attribute in teh controller....

Comment: @BradWerth What do you mean?

Comment: Well, in addition to the steps you outlined above, you will also want to have protections in the controller. In case someone guesses at a bunch of attributes ("paid", "admin", etc) and submits a malicious  request using them.

Comment: You may want to make a parent controller that checks if user is paid. And show 404 or 403 if they try to access the paid page without paying

Comment: @BradWerth oh ok. I'll look into that, any idea on how I can implement the checkbox part tho?

Comment: @Ruslan Hey! How exactly do I do that? If you could add an answer with a tad bit longer explanation, that would be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

In the form for the admin:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'paid', 'yes', true %>
  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

Then in the controller:

```
class ClientController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_client, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index 
end

def show
end

def new
    @client = current_user.build_client
end

def create
    @client = current_user.build_client(client_params)
    if @client.save
      redirect_to clients_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
end

def update
end

def destroy
    @client.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
end

private
    def client_params
       if current_user.user_type == :admin
         # This is different because only admin can update paid
         # To make a string a boolean             
         params[:client][:paid] = params[:client][:paid] == 'yes' 
         params.require(:client).permit(:paid, :name, :company, :position, :number, :email, :client_img)
       else       
         params.require(:client).permit(:name, :company, :position, :number, :email, :client_img)
      end
    end

    def find_client
        @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    end 
end
```

you can do this more properly using the protected attributes, [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409783/cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes-in-rails-4)

After that you want to make a `PaidController`

```
class PaidController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authorize_paid

    def authorize_paid
      return head(:forbidden) unless current_user.paid?
    end
end
```

Then make sure that all the protected pages inherit from the `PaidController`

Comment: Can you please explain this line to me --> <%= check_box_tag 'paid', 'yes', true %>

Comment: I also updated my answer with the actual code I have. The original question was simplified to make it easier to understand. Please let me know if your answer changes due to the changes I made. You are amazing

Comment: @LizzyTheLearner The check_box_tag http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag creates a check box. The argumatents are: name, value when checked and is it checked by default. You can set the last one  to false

Comment: Oh ok. So in my case, by default, it should NOT be checked. Which means, by default, client had NOT paid yet. So I'm going to leave it at that. When I click on it, indicating the client has paid, current_user.paid? will return true?

Comment: @LizzyTheLearner Yes, set the last variable to false. `paid?` is a active record helper to check if the attribute is not nil or false

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529997/check-box-tag-doesnt-retain-value-in-rails-app Check this out please

Comment: Thanks for helping me Ruslan