# Check_box_tag doesn't retain value in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called "Clients". The Clients model belongs to the Users model (Users model is associated with devise). There is another model called "sellers", but they aren't involved in the question. The Client can do payments to me manually (cash only). When the client does this payment, I give them access to more pages in the website. To do this, I added a boolean variable called "paid" to my clients and then the admin(me) can go to their client profile, update the paid status from 'unpaid' to 'paid' through a checkbox. Only the admin can view the checkbox.

This is the form partial for updating client information:

```
<%= simple_form_for @client do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: 'Full name', error: 'Full name is mandatory' %>
  <%= f.input :company, label: 'Name of company' %>
  <%= f.input :position, label: 'Position you hold at your company' %>
  <%= f.input :number, label: 'Phone number' %>
  <%= f.input :email, label: 'Enter email address' %>
  <%= f.file_field :emp_img, label: 'Profile picture' %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'paid', 'yes', false %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Then my client controller is:

```
class ClientController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_client, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index 
end

def show
end

def new
    @client = current_user.build_client
end

def create
    @client = current_user.build_client(client_params)
    if @client.save
      redirect_to clients_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
end

def update
end

def destroy
    @client.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
end

private
    def client_params
       if current_user.user_type == :admin           
         params[:client][:paid] = params[:client][:paid] == 'yes' 
         params.require(:client).permit(:paid, :name, :company, :position, :number, :email, :client_img)
       else       
         params.require(:client).permit(:name, :company, :position, :number, :email, :client_img)
      end
    end

    def find_client
        @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    end 
end
```

When I go to the client profile, and click on "update" info, I get the form partial, in that, the check box is not checked. I click it and update the profile, no errors, takes me back to the profile. But when I click update again, the check box is unchecked. It doesn't retain the value of the check box ONLY. Everything else is retained. Like the name, company and all that. When I go into the rails c, the paid variable is still false even if I click on it and update it. Does anyone know why it might be so?

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#available-input-types-and-defaults-for-each-column-type. Use `<%= f.input  :paid, as: :boolean %>`

Comment: @Ruslan Same thing, it doesn't get retained. No error or anything. But every time the form loads, it's unchecked. Why doesn't it update? :( Is it something in the controller not saving the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use check_box form helper in place of `check_box_tag` into the form, and remove line from `client_params` method:

```
params[:client][:paid] = params[:client][:paid] == 'yes'
```

Comment: I thought that line checked if the client has paid, and if so, then permit (:paid) in client params. Am I wrong?

Comment: You don't need to customize the value of paid at controller side. paid will automatically would have true/false as per check_box is selected or not.